# Slow jQuery selector when selecting class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdName">Smith</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_smith_01">1</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_smith_02">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_smith_03">1</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_smith_04">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_smith_05">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdName">Miller</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_miller_01">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_miller_02">2</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_miller_03">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_miller_04">2</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_miller_05">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdName">Underwood</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_underwood_01">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_underwood_02">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_underwood_03">1</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_underwood_04">1</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_underwood_05">%nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdName">Stinson</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_stinson_01">2</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_stinson_02">2</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_stinson_03">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_stinson_04">%nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tdTime" id="td_stinson_05">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In reality it's way larger and more complex. Now I want to add a click listener do each and every time cell of the table, so every cell of the class "tdTime", so I added:

```
    var tdTimes = $(".tdTime");
    tdTimes.onclick( 
        function() {
            switch($(this).html()) {
                ...a switch to change the time in the td.
            } 
        }
    );
```

As I mentioned the real table is much bigger (length of tdTimes > 15,000) and so the IE needs about ~8,000ms to add the listener to every cell, Chrome still needs about 3,000ms. On many sites it's suggested to use ids as a selector to make this faster but as you can see I already have ids in use and it is nearly impossible for me to use those ids in that case because the table is - again - a lot more complex than the simple example.

What would you suggest to speed up the process? In another post I read about a tip to give the selectors a context, should I maybe give the table rows an consecutive id ("trTime1", "trTime2", ...), then remember the amount of those rows and later do a for loop to add the listener? Something like:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= trTimelength; i++) {
    var tdTimes = $('.tdTime', '#trTime' + i)
    tdTimes.click(
        ...
    )
};
```

Thanks for your help, guys!

EDIT: As A. Wolff correctly mentioned 15,000 cells are way too many to display - I would therefor like to add, that most of those cells are hidden at the start. So after the page is loaded I have no problem with performance. (But unfortunately the cells need the listener anyway)

Comment: You should paginate your table. Showing more than 15,000 cells at once is just too much. That's said, you could still delegate event to TABLE level and avoid more than 15,000 handlers

Comment: Also wouldn't you have multiple similar ids - I'm guessing you could have multiple Smiths in your table

Comment: Agreed. There are usability concerns with 3000 rows on one page on top of your performance concerns.

Comment: Don't add the listener to td's but their parent table. And then refer to the td element as evt.target.

Comment: As @BuddhiP answered, attach an event handler to the elements you want to handle. Also, 'On' takes care of elements that are dynamically created/attached to the table. It is a one time event delegation.

Comment: @Pete The ids aren't really td_smith_04 but td_ssmith_04, td_msmith_04 according to the username of that person, so it's unique.

Comment: And also thanks to you guys for your tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not attach event handler to each cell. It's very inefficient, and consumes a lot of memory.

Use event bubbling feature and attach a handler to higher level element, to the table in this case.

try something like

```
$("table#tblid").on("click", "td.tdTime", function(e) { 
    console.log("Td clicked", e);
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

NOTE: As correctly mentioned in the comment (by @A.Wolf) below this is not a shortcut for adding all the handlers at once. This ads only a single handler to the table element which contains all the td elements. Table can see the click event on child td, because of the mechanism known as 'event propagation' or 'event bubbling'. It uses much less resources than and less error prone than adding handlers to individual elements. It works even if you dynamically add td elements later on to the table.

Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/prv6y/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Great! Works like a charme! Thanks for that. Now it adds the listener to all cells in whooping 3ms! :))

Comment: @cheeZer No, it doesn't add a listener for each cell, that's the purpose of delegation to avoid it ;) But anyway, you issue is more in the fact to display so much data at once. Each time you'll have to manipulate these datas in the DOM, you'll call for trouble. You should  use this kind of plugin and use pagination: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Sure, you're right, it doesn't add the listener to each cell ;-)

But as I mentioned above, most of the table rows are hidden, so you only see like 100 at a time.